# Contructor de un array de objetos - Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, object

Estoy usando `typescript` para programar en Angular2. Tengo un objecto `car.ts` the es de la siguiente forma:

```
export class Car{
    name: String;
    door: {
        position: String;
        id: Number;
    };
}
```

He inicializado el objecto de la siguiente forma:

```
constructor() {
    this.door= new Door();
}
export class Door{
    position: String;
    ID: Number
}
```

Y funciona correctamente. Mi problema viene cuando intento incializar un array de objectos:

```
export class Car{
    name: String;
    door: {
        position: String;
        id: Number;
    };
    color: [{
       one: String;
       two: String;

    }]
}
```

y lo intento de la siguiente manera;

```
constructor() {
        this.color= new Color();
        this.door= new Door();
    }


export class Color{
    one: String;
    two: String;
}
```

El error es el siguiente:

> Type Color is not assignable to type...

Imagino que el error es porque la clase Receivers no crea un `Array`

Comment: Probaste separando los objetos con , y no con ;?

Answer (score 0):

Hazlo de la siguiente forma

**Clase:**

```
export class Car{
    name: String;
    door: {
        position: String;
        id: Number;
    };
    color: Color[];
}
```

**Constructor:** (Array vacio)

```
constructor() {
        this.color = new Array<Color>(); 
// De esta forma inicializa un array vació de Colores, y la variable ya tiene el tipo (Color[]) en su declaración
        this.door= new Door();
    }
```

**Constructor:** (Array con objetos vacios)

```
constructor() {
            this.color = [new Color() (, new Color(), ..)]
    // De esta forma inicializa un array con un objetos Color (vacios), o mas como se muestra entre paracentesis "()"
            this.door= new Door();
        }
```

Comment: Lo he intentado crear así, pero ahora me dice undefined también en la primera pos

Comment: Lógico, porque esta vació el array. Interprete que querías inicializar el  Array para que sea de tipo Color, si quieres hacerlo con Objetos Color vacíos en su interior, ahora te agrego el código.

Comment: "[TS] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type Colors has not compatible call signatures" Es es el error que me da cuando escribo "this.colors=  [new Colors() (,new Colors(), ..)]"

Comment: Es Color, la class, según el código de la pregunta. Ese error quiere decir que no es compatible el retorno con lo declarado. PD: Los paracentesis indican como podría seguir agregando objetos, no van.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema viene en varias partes:

```
export class Car{
name: String;
door: {
    position: String;
    id: Number;
};
color: [{
   one: String;<---- esto deberia ser ',' en lugar de ';'
   two: String;

}]
```

}

En este punto acabas de declarar el miembro 'color' como un array que **contiene al menos un objeto** con 2 atributos (one y two). Para que tu codigo de inicializacion funcione deberia ser:

```
 constructor() {
    this.color = [{ one: "", two: "" }, new Color(), {one:"",two:""}]; 
    this.door= new Door();
}
```

donde el primer elemento bien puede ser de la clase Color o cualquier objeto que satisfaga la restriccion especificada (que tenga los atributos one y two solamente). 
Si lo que querias era especificar un array de un tipo en especifico, entonces puedes hacerlo de varias maneras:

```
  color: {one:String, two:String }[];
```

o asi:

```
  color: Color[];
```

o asi:

```
  color:Array<{one:String, two:String }>
```

o asi:

```
  color:Array<Color>
```

Espero que esto responda a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

**Object** Al final he creado un `array` y no un `tuple`

```
export class Car{
    name: String;
    door: {
        position: String;
        id: Number;
    };
    color: {
       one: String;
       two: String;

    }[]
}
```

**Constructor** He creado un constructor en el que se realiza un `push` por cada uno de los elementos creados. El número de elementos creados depende de una variable elegida cada vez que se crea dicho objecto.

```
constructor() {
        this.door= new Door();
        for (var i = 0; i < receivers; i++) {
            this.door.push(new Door);
        }
        this.color= [];
    }
export class Color{
    one: String;
    two: String;
}
```